# Can we have same category name in X axis of Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart in my application and I want to show how sales have been happening over past months and I want to show months of three years. SO the X axis should be something like following. Earlier I had a requirement like to show the year as a group and months of each year as sub grpups similar to following image. [Grouped Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fydu.png)

I achieved it through [BlackLabel](http://https:https//github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories) plugin. But now I want to check whether we can have months on the XAxix without year categorization. So only the months will be displayed on XAxix. So it should be like following second image.Is there a way to do this? Sample code is as follows.
[Expected Way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do4AV.png)

```
    Highcharts.chart('container-main-bar', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {


      },
      drillup: function(e) {


      }
    },
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Car Sales'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      formatter() {
        return `<span style="color: #626262">${this.value}</span>`
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Sales'
    },
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
      formatter() {
        return `<span style="color: #626262">${this.value}</span>`
      }
    }

  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.y}'
      },
    },
  },

  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">Sales as at</span><br>',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.date}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> <br/>'
  },

  "series": [{
    "name": "Australia",
    "data": [{
        "name": "Jan",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year5',

      },
      {
        "name": "Feb",
        "y": 40,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year4',

      },
      {
        "name": "Mar",
        "y": 50,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year3',

      },
      {
        "name": "Apr",
        "y": 30,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year2',

      },
      {
        "name": "May",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year1',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jun",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jul",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Aug",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Sep",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Oct",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Nov",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Dec",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jan",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Feb",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',
      },
      {
        "name": "Mar",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',
      },
      {
        "name": "Apr",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "May",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jun",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jul",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Aug",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Sep",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Oct",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Nov",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Dec",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jan",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Feb",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Mar",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Apr",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "May",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jun",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Jul",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Aug",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Sep",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Oct",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Nov",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      },
      {
        "name": "Dec",
        "y": 20,
        "color": '#ff910c',
        "drilldown": 'Year0',

      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbmauks/32/

Comment: What if you make it like this
Jan-2017, Feb-2017...,Jan-2018, Feb-2018..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the same category names, but you have to set:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    uniqueNames: false
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y4xa5e7w/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.uniqueNames

Comment: In the live demo, if I change x values to string chart does not render.  using [] (example ['NY', 1]) for x & y values works with string. This notation does not permit name property. But, I need to use x value as string and need name property as well. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Hi @frosty, You can not use `x` value as a string. If the first value in data array is a string, it is applied as the name of the point.